# How to determine whether a column/variable is numeric or not in Pandas/NumPy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is there a better way to determine whether a variable in `Pandas` and/or `NumPy` is `numeric` or not ?

I have a self defined `dictionary` with `dtypes` as keys and `numeric` / `not` as values.

Comment: You could check `dtype.kind in 'biufc'`.

Comment: The comment above this one posted by Jaime, was simpler than the ones below and seems to have worked perfectly......thanks

Answer (score 199):

In `pandas 0.20.2` you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.types import is_string_dtype
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]})

is_string_dtype(df['A'])
>>>> True

is_numeric_dtype(df['B'])
>>>> True
```

Comment: It appears that `is_numeric_dtype` returns `True` for _boolean_ type as well.

Comment: Yes @ManojGovindan, because booleans are integers in Python. You can apply operations such as multiplication to them, basically, a Bool is an integer that can be valued 0 or 1.

Comment: for decimal `is_numeric_dtype` returns `False`

Comment: `is_integer_dtype` is also useful.

Answer (score 102):

You can use [`np.issubdtype`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.issubdtype.html) to check if the dtype is a sub dtype of `np.number`. Examples:

```
np.issubdtype(arr.dtype, np.number)  # where arr is a numpy array
np.issubdtype(df['X'].dtype, np.number)  # where df['X'] is a pandas Series
```

This works for numpy's dtypes but fails for pandas specific types like pd.Categorical as Thomas [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900202/how-to-determine-whether-a-column-variable-is-numeric-or-not-in-pandas-numpy/38185759?noredirect=1#comment86577517_38185759). If you are using categoricals [`is_numeric_dtype`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45568283/2285236) function from pandas is a better alternative than np.issubdtype.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 
                   'C': [1j, 2j, 3j], 'D': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
df
Out: 
   A    B   C  D
0  1  1.0  1j  a
1  2  2.0  2j  b
2  3  3.0  3j  c

df.dtypes
Out: 
A         int64
B       float64
C    complex128
D        object
dtype: object
```

---

```
np.issubdtype(df['A'].dtype, np.number)
Out: True

np.issubdtype(df['B'].dtype, np.number)
Out: True

np.issubdtype(df['C'].dtype, np.number)
Out: True

np.issubdtype(df['D'].dtype, np.number)
Out: False
```

For multiple columns you can use np.vectorize:

```
is_number = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.issubdtype(x, np.number))
is_number(df.dtypes)
Out: array([ True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

And for selection, pandas now has [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
Out: 
   A    B   C
0  1  1.0  1j
1  2  2.0  2j
2  3  3.0  3j
```

Comment: This does not seem to work reliably with pandas DataFrames, since those might return categories unknown to numpy like "category". Numpy then throws "TypeError: data type not understood"

Answer (score 55):

Based on @jaime's answer in the comments, you need to check `.dtype.kind` for the column of interest. For example;

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'numeric': [1, 2, 3], 'not_numeric': ['A', 'B', 'C']})
>>> df['numeric'].dtype.kind in 'biufc'
>>> True
>>> df['not_numeric'].dtype.kind in 'biufc'
>>> False
```

NB The meaning of `biufc`: `b` bool, `i` int (signed), `u` unsigned int, `f` float, `c` complex. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.kind.html#numpy.dtype.kind

Comment: Here is the list of all dtype kinds [1]. Lowercase `u` is for unsigned integer; uppercase `U` is for unicode.

[1]: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.kind.html

Answer (score 11):

DataFrames have the [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) method. This will return a subset of the DataFrame which only includes the "numeric" columns (columns of dtype **int64**/**float64**).

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['int64', 'float64'])
```

Comment: Maybe one could even do `include=np.number` (`import numpy as np`)

Comment: How does this perform, compared with a read-only check like inspecting the columns dtypes?

Answer (score 5):

This is a pseudo-internal method to return only the numeric type data

```
In [27]: df = DataFrame(dict(A = np.arange(3), 
                             B = np.random.randn(3), 
                             C = ['foo','bar','bah'], 
                             D = Timestamp('20130101')))

In [28]: df
Out[28]: 
   A         B    C                   D
0  0 -0.667672  foo 2013-01-01 00:00:00
1  1  0.811300  bar 2013-01-01 00:00:00
2  2  2.020402  bah 2013-01-01 00:00:00

In [29]: df.dtypes
Out[29]: 
A             int64
B           float64
C            object
D    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

In [30]: df._get_numeric_data()
Out[30]: 
   A         B
0  0 -0.667672
1  1  0.811300
2  2  2.020402
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying to figure how do they do that. One would expect an internal IsNumeric function ran per column... but still didn't find it in the code

Comment: You can apply this per column, but much easier just to check the dtype. in any event pandas operations exclude non-numeric when needed. what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

How about just checking type for one of the values in the column? We've always had something like this:

```
isinstance(x, (int, long, float, complex))
```

When I try to check the datatypes for the columns in below dataframe, I get them as 'object' and not a numerical type I'm expecting:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('time', 'test1', 'test2'))
for i in range(20):
    df.loc[i] = [datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=i*1000),i*10,i*100]
df.dtypes

time     datetime64[ns]
test1            object
test2            object
dtype: object
```

When I do the following, it seems to give me accurate result:

```
isinstance(df['test1'][len(df['test1'])-1], (int, long, float, complex))
```

returns

```
True
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check whether a given column contains numeric values or not using dtypes

```
numerical_features = [feature for feature in train_df.columns if train_df[feature].dtypes != 'O']
```

Note: "O" should be capital

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

```
df_dtypes = np.array(df.dtypes)
df_numericDtypes= [x.kind in 'bifc' for x in df_dtypes]
```

It returns a list of booleans: `True` if numeric, `False` if not.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to all other answers, one can also use `df.info()` to get whats the data type of each column.

Comment: Or just `df.dtypes`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep your data in the same type, I found the following works similar to `df._get_numeric_data()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 
                   'C': [4.0, 'x2', 6], 'D': [np.nan]*3})

test_dtype_df = df.loc[:, df.apply(lambda s: s.dtype.kind in 'biufc')]
test_dtype_df.shape == df._get_numeric_data().shape
Out[1]: True
```

However, if you want to test whether a series converts properly, you can use "ignore" :

```
df_ = df.copy().apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
test_nmr_ignore = df_.loc[:, df_.apply(lambda s: s.dtype.kind in 'biufc')]

display(test_nmr_ignore)
test_nmr_ignore.shape == df._get_numeric_data().shape,\
test_nmr_ignore.shape == df_._get_numeric_data().shape,\
test_nmr_ignore.shape
     B   D
0  1.0 NaN
1  2.0 NaN
2  3.0 NaN
Out[2]: (True, True, (3, 2))
```

Finally, in the case where some data is mixed, you can use `coerce` with the `pd.to_numeric` function, and then drop columns that are filled completely with `np.nan` values.

```
df_ = df.copy().apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
test_nmr_coerce = df_.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
display(test_nmr_coerce)
     B    C
0  1.0  4.0
1  2.0  NaN
2  3.0  6.0
```

You may have to determine which columns are `np.nan` values in the original data for accuracy. I merged the original `np.nan` columns back in with the converted data, `df_`:

```
nacols = [c for c in df.columns if c not in df.dropna(axis=1, how='all').columns]
display(pd.merge(test_nmr_coerce, 
                 df[nacols], 
                 right_index=True, left_index=True))
     B    C   D
0  1.0  4.0 NaN
1  2.0  NaN NaN
2  3.0  6.0 NaN
```