# Merging and sorting all indexed columns in one single column in a single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a dataframe which looks like this. It has more time axes till `Time[s].30`.

```
Time[s]    v1   Time[s].1   v2
160.84621   0   160.84808   7
161.14613   0   161.14802   7
161.538245  27  161.540085  7
162.01598   27  162.017865  7
162.31589   27  162.317775  7
162.615855  27  162.617735  7
162.915765  27  162.91765   7
163.21574   27  163.217625  7
163.51569   27  163.517575  7
163.81563   27  163.81751   7
164.11554   27  164.117425  7
164.4155    27  164.41738   9
164.71543   27  164.717315  9
165.015405  27  165.017285  9
165.31532   27  165.317205  9
165.65083   26  165.65272   9
165.95025   26  165.95214   9
```

I want a single time axis `Time[s].general` which is a merged form of all Time columns with sorted values. I have indexed all those columns.

```
df.set_index(keys=list(file_read.filter(like='Time[s]').columns))
```

**UPDATE:**

Expected output:

```
Time[s]      v1     v2
160.84621   0      null 
160.84808   null     7
160.14613   0      null
161.14802   null     7
161.538245  27     null
161.540085  null     7
162.01598   27     null
162.017865  null     7
162.31589   27     null
162.317775  null     7
```

And so on.

UPDATE 2:

```
Time[s]    v1   Time[s].1   v2      Time[s].2   v3
160.84621   0   160.84808   7   158.538395  Active
161.14613   0   161.14802   7   158.538515  Active
161.538245  27  161.540085  7   159.49455   Active
162.01598   27  162.017865  7   162.352395  Locked
162.31589   27  162.317775  7   163.35075   Locked
162.615855  27  162.617735  7   164.350675  Locked
162.915765  27  162.91765   7   165.350655  Locked
163.21574   27  163.217625  7   166.509695  Locked
163.51569   27  163.517575  7   166.509815  Locked
163.81563   27  163.81751   7   167.50086   Locked
164.11554   27  164.117425  7   168.50085   Locked
164.4155    27  164.41738   9   169.500865  Locked
164.71543   27  164.717315  9   171.502655  Standby
165.015405  27  165.017285  9   185.89923   Forward
165.31532   27  165.317205  9   3273.448065 Forward
165.65083   26  165.65272   9   3274.43487  Forward
165.95025   26  165.95214   9   3275.4348   Forward
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need:

```
b  = df.filter(like='v').columns

d = {x: 'v.{}'.format(i) for i, x in enumerate(b)}
d['Time[s]'] = 'Time[s].0'
print (d)
{'v1': 'v0', 'v2': 'v1', 'Time[s]': 'Time[s].0'}

df = df.rename(columns=d)
L = [x.set_index(x.columns[0]) for i, x in df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('.')[-1], axis=1)]
df = pd.concat(L, axis=1)
print (df.head(10))
             v.0  v.1
160.846210   0.0  NaN
160.848080   NaN  7.0
161.146130   0.0  NaN
161.148020   NaN  7.0
161.538245  27.0  NaN
161.540085   NaN  7.0
162.015980  27.0  NaN
162.017865   NaN  7.0
162.315890  27.0  NaN
162.317775   NaN  7.0
```

**Expanation**:

1. First [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) columns all `v` columns for dictionary for pairs timestamps with values columns.
2. `rename` by `dict`, also first `timestamp` column
3. `groupby` by values of columna after `.` in list comprehension, create index by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) together

EDIT:

If numeric values and duplicated timestamp aggregation is by `mean`, if not, aggreagation by `first`:

```
b  = df.filter(like='v').columns

d = {x: 'v.{}'.format(i) for i, x in enumerate(b)}
d['Time[s]'] = 'Time[s].0'
print (d)
{'v1': 'v0', 'v2': 'v1', 'Time[s]': 'Time[s].0'}

df = df.rename(columns=d)
L = [x.groupby(x.columns[0]).mean() 
     if np.issubdtype(df[x.columns[1]].dtype, np.number)
     else x.groupby(x.columns[0]).first() 
     for i, x in df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('.').str[-1], axis=1)]

df = pd.concat(L, axis=1)
print (df.head(10))
             v.0  v.1     v.2
158.538395   NaN  NaN  Active
158.538515   NaN  NaN  Active
159.494550   NaN  NaN  Active
160.846210   0.0  NaN     NaN
160.848080   NaN  7.0     NaN
161.146130   0.0  NaN     NaN
161.148020   NaN  7.0     NaN
161.538245  27.0  NaN     NaN
161.540085   NaN  7.0     NaN
162.015980  27.0  NaN     NaN
```

Comment: I have tried the first solution, but I need something different. Time axis is perfect, but I don't want to put all `v` columns in one column. I want those to be there. After the sort happens in the new Time axis, I want all the `v` columns to arrange accordingly. I will update the expected output in the question. Times where the `v` value is not present, I want to put a `null`.

Comment: @tworitdash - Please check completely changed solution.

Comment: I got an error at `df = pd.concat(L, axis=1)` which says `Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: @tworitdash - I find typo, need `d = {x: 'v.{}'.format(i) for i, x in enumerate(b)}` instaed `d = {x: 'v{}'.format(i) for i, x in enumerate(b)}`

Comment: @tworitdash - But if still error it means there are duplicated `date`s values in some column. So is possible aggregatte duplicates, e.g. by `mean` - `L = [x.groupby(x.columns[0]).mean() for i, x in df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('.').str[-1], axis=1)]`

Comment: I had changed the typo before, no problem! However, I can see there is no duplicate columns. I tried aggregating but I got this `No numeric types to aggregate`

Comment: It seem values column is necessary convert to numeric. Untested code `L = [pd.to_numeric(x[x.columns[1]],errors='coerce').groupby(x[x.columns[0]]).mean() for i, x in df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('.').str[-1], axis=1)]`

Comment: Let me try that

Comment: One more doubt. I actually had some string data as well. Now, those are not showing, only numeric values are showing up.

Comment: @tworitdash - not so easy, now I am on phone only. Main question is how aggregate data if strings? If check df.dtypes it return object only for string data? Or is possible some numeric are saved as strings, e.g. because mixed numeric with non numeric?

Comment: Some data columns are strings. dtype is object, yes. Example I will update in the question.

Comment: @tworitdash - so if string, is possible aggregate by first?

Comment: This gives me output in only one column. I am confused.

Comment: @tworitdash - I add alternative, can you check it?

Comment: @tworitdash - ooops, I fint bug. Give me a sec.

Comment: Yes, I also found it.`Can only use .str accessor with string values (i.e. inferred_type is 'string', 'unicode' or 'mixed')` Okay!

Comment: @tworitdash - there was problem with check if number, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38185759/2901002) solution is used now. Check last edit, please.

Comment: Worked. Done! Thank you.