# Filter Pandas Dataframe only with Float32 dtype

Tags: python, pandas

I have this method which I need to apply only for columns which are `'float32'` not all columns.

```
def preprocess(self, dataframe):
    if self._means is None: 
      self._means = np.mean(dataframe, axis=0)

    if self._stds is None:
      self._stds = np.std(dataframe, axis=0)
      if not self._stds.all():
        raise ValueError('At least one column has std deviation of 0.')

    return (dataframe - self._means) / self._stds
```

I collect the type like this, but looking for the Pythonic way to do it:

```
dtypes = list(zip(dataframe.dtypes.index, map(str, dataframe.dtypes)))
# Normalize numeric columns.
 for column, dtype in dtypes:
    if dtype == 'float32':
```

Comment: Does this help? [38185759](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900202/how-to-determine-whether-a-column-variable-is-numeric-or-not-in-pandas-numpy/38185759)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a series of the columns that are of type float32 like this:

```
cols = dataframe.columns[dataframe.dtypes == 'float32']
```

then pass those to your function:

```
dataframe[cols].apply(preprocess)
```

Answer (score 3):

`pandas` way will be first extract the numeric `columns` with `select_dtypes`

```
subdf= df.select_dtypes(include='float32') 
subdf=subdf.apply(preprocess,axis=1)
df[list(subdf)]=subdf
```