# How to make a scatter plot with non-numerical column?

Tags: python, bokeh, scatter-plot

If I want to make a scatter plot in `matplotlib` I can do:

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(1, 6), 'b': list('ABCDE')})

plt.scatter(df['a'], df['b'])
plt.show()
```

Which gives

[image]

How would I get the same output in `bokeh`?

I tried (same set-up as above):

```
source = ColumnDataSource(df)    

p = figure(
    title="Something great",
    tools='save,pan,box_zoom,reset,wheel_zoom',
    background_fill_color="#fafafa"
)

p.scatter(
    'a',
    'b',
    source=source
)

show(p)
```

but that does not plot anything. If I plot column `a` against itself it works fine, suggesting that the code structure is fine, but that it only works for numerical values. Is there a quick fix to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y_range` parameter fixed the issue for me.

I found it at [Handling Categorical Data](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#adding-jitter).

```py
p = figure(
    y_range=df['b'], # < -- what I added 
    title="Something great",
    tools='save,pan,box_zoom,reset,wheel_zoom',
    background_fill_color="#fafafa"
)
```

[image]

Comment: That indeed works. Unfortunately, it seems that I cannot just also add `x_range=df['a']`, so seems - if I want a general solution for a scatter plot - I first have to check whether the selected column is numerical and if not add the respective `x/y_range` argument. Can be done using the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45568283/1534017).