# Stating which columns are numerical values only and stating it in original data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Below I have a data frame and I also know how to find out which column is numerical values only. However I am having trouble figuring out how to produce something like my desired_results where it maintains the original column names but removes all rows and just states 'numerical' for number columns and blanks for the other.

Data

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'column1' : ['1','2','3','4'],
      'column2' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})
df2['column1'] = df2['column1'].astype('int')
```

Code to find out which columns are numerical values

```
list(df2.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns.values)
```

Desired result

```
desired_results = pd.DataFrame({'column1' : ['numerical'],
      'column2' : ['']})
```

Comment: What is the particular problem? You can retrieve a list of all column names and you have a list of numeric columns so you just can create the dictionary like the one in the last snippet to build the dataframe?

Comment: A lot more answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900202/how-to-determine-whether-a-column-variable-is-numeric-or-not-in-pandas-numpy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
num_cols = list(df2.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns.values)
values = ["numerical" if c in num_cols else "" for c in df2.columns]
# values: ['numerical', '']

desired_result = pd.DataFrame(values).T
desired_result.columns = df2.columns
# desired_result:
#      column1 column2
# 0  numerical
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `to_numeric` to try convert all into numerical values:

```
df2.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').notnull().all()
```

Output:

```
column1     True
column2    False
dtype: bool
```