# Python using Pandas - Retrieving the name of all columns that contain numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I searched for a solution on the site, but I couldn't find anything relevant, only outdated code. I am new to the Pandas library and I have the following `dataframe` as an example:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 142 | 0.4 | red | 108 | front |
| 164 | 1.3 | green | 98 | rear |
| 71 | -1.0 | blue | 234 | front |
| 109 | 0.2 | black | 120 | front |

I would like to extract the name of the columns that contain numbers (integers and floats). It is completely fine to use the first row to achieve this.
So the result should look like this: `['A', 'B', 'D']`

I tried the following command to get some of the columns that contained numbers:

```
dataframe.loc[0, dataframe.dtypes == 'int64']

Out:
A 142
D 108
```

There are two problems with this. First of all, I just need the name of the columns, but not the values. Second, this captures only the integer columns. My next attempt just gave an error:

```
dataframe.loc[0, dataframe.dtypes == 'int64' or dataframe.dtypes == 'float64']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine whether a column/variable is numeric or not in Pandas/NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900202/how-to-determine-whether-a-column-variable-is-numeric-or-not-in-pandas-numpy)

Comment: It should be `dataframe.loc[0, (dataframe.dtypes == 'int64') | (dataframe.dtypes == 'float64')]`. I don't know why [pandas uses these characters though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54358361/11235205)

Comment: But Marcelo answer is the better way though

Comment: @MarceloPaco It is one step closer to the solution, but I still don't get the name of the columns that contain numeric values.

Comment: @Minh-LongLuu Your code did work! However, I still need to retrieve just the column names without any data.

Comment: @Adrian you should move your comment to here. Btw, you can read only the first row via the parameter nrows: pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', nrows=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
dataframe.select_dtypes('number').columns.tolist()
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'D']
```

Comment: This is a very compact solution, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dtype.html) then [`.kind`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.kind.html) while filtering the the [column names](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html) with [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension).

```py
# import pandas as pd
# df = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75909965')[0] # scraped your q

[c for c in df.columns if df[c].dtype.kind in 'iufc']
```

should return `['A', 'B', 'D']`. [Note that *`'iufc'`* covers signed and unsigned integers as well as real and complex floating-point numbers. Add `b` if you want to cover Booleans as well since they're a subclass of `int` in python....]

Comment: This is also a very interesting solution, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Marcelo's comment, you can use:

```py
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype

numeric_columns = []
for column in df.columns:
    if is_numeric_dtype(df[column]):
        numeric_columns.append(column)
print(numeric_columns)
```

Comment: @Adrian you should move your comment to here. Btw, you can read only the first row via the parameter `nrows`: `pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', nrows=1)`

Comment: Thank you, this code did the job too.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibles solution:

```
import re

df.columns[
    [re.match(r'^(int|float)', x.name) != None for x in df.dtypes]].to_list()
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'D']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below function:

First it select all the numeric columns, then it finds the columns, which is finally converted into list.

```
df.select_dtypes(include="number").columns.to_list()
```